# ESLINT: Format JS functions to not break params and callback into multiple lines

Tags: javascript, eslint, code-formatting

I'm struggling with trying to prevent function params from breaking a function into multiple lines. I tried to use `"function-paren-newline": ["error", { "minItems": 3 }]`, but I think this just breaks the parens to new lines. Is there a way to limit the params/callback from breaking into new line?

For example (in angular):

```
$scope.$watch(
  'hello',
  function() {
    sayHi($scope.name)
  },
  true
);
```

Ideally, I would like it to be like below:

```
$scope.$watch('hello', function() {
  sayHi($scope.name)
}, true);
```